# Why do my animation sounds play in the beginning of test movie?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a game where a cutscene comes in a specific order and after you press the play button, the play button page gets removed and we add another child which is the "animation movieclip page". This movieclip is a page with animations and sounds that play inside of it.

At first the menu page with the buttons come up, but animation page doesn't come up unless you press play.

Why do my sounds from the animation movieclip come up when it's not even added to the stage yet?

So the sounds from the animation movieclip played before adding to stage.

Comment: How did you instantiate your movieclip ( which contain the sound ), by AS3 code or adding it directly to your Stage ?

Comment: I use it with AS3 Code.

Comment: Did you instantiate it at the first, and then when the user press the play button, you add it to a display object container ? Could you give us more details about that ?

Comment: I instantiated the button page first, then when I press the play button, the animation page gets added and the button page gets deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you without looking your coding. And i use imagination
to solve your problem.

Try adding `addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);`

Example

```
public class MyClass extends AnimationClip {
        public function MyClass():void {
            if(stage) {
                init();
            } else {
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
            }
        }
```

Hope this helpful.

Comment: I actually used the timeline for the sounds and animations, not code.

Comment: I don't know if there is another solution for this, but I added that code on the beginning of my animation and it seemed to not play the sounds UNLESS the animation was actually added to stage.

Comment: @Crook You can also put your sound in the frame 2, and a `stop()` in the 1st one, and then `mc.gotoAndPlay(2)` ...